# Build a simple class library for ASP.NET Core and MVC 5 Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to build a simple *C# Class Library* that can be referenced from both *ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC* and *MVC 5* web applications.  By *simple* I mean that the library just contains some *enums* and some *string constants*, i.e. no additional dependencies.

I have tried building the library as a .NET Core Class Library, but it seems this cannot be referenced by MVC 5 applications and vice versa.  Currently, all components (class library and web applications) are running in the same solution.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider shared project instead?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Comment: @DavidL That link is outdated (even though it was posted less than 10 months ago). A month before this blog post, Microsoft announced that it was moved away from  `project.json` project to the `csproj` format (for .Net Core Tooling). See => [blogs.msdn.microsoft.com -
 Changes to Project.json](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) So I'm not sure if this link is applicable anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a .NET Standard class library. Be sure to pick a version of the .NET standard that both .net core and full framework supports (1.5 works for 4.6.2 and net core)

See matrix in this article for full compatibilities:

#### [blogs.msdn.microsoft.com - Introducing .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but when I Add a 'New Project' in VS 2017, I see Visual C# -> .Net Standard -> Class Library (.NET Standard)  How do I configure the .NET Standard that I want/need?  All I see the drop-down is  .NET Framework 4 through to 4.6.2.  Thanks.

Comment: Make the project, then in the properties page, under "Application" there's a framework version dropdown.

Comment: My problem appears to be that I have a .NETCoreApp 1.1 and an MVC 5 4.6.2 application, and there doesn't seem to be a common .NET Standard for these.

Comment: 1.4 or 1.5 works fine with both. I just built a test app to double check and both the .net core and full framework app both build fine linking in a common class from a 1.4 .net standard lib.

Comment: So I have a Class Library `Identity.Common` built against .NETStandard 1.5.  I then have a second class library `Identity.Common.Eu` built against .NET Framework 4.5.2.  I can add a reference to the first library, but I cannot resolve any references that it defines.  Thanks for your help/patience.  The second library is used gainst MVC 5 applications only.

Comment: For 4.5.2 target .Net Standard 1.1

Comment: OK, so I have now tried all .NETStandards 1.0 thru' 1.6.  The .NET 4.5.2 dependent class libraries and web applications can never resolve the references in the base library.

Comment: I have (just double-checked).  I'm beginning to suspect a wider problem, perhaps with VS, as I an now getting irregular builds (clean, rebuild all twice gives different results).  I'm going to go home and try this on a different PC to see if that changes anything - maybe a cache issue...).  Once again, than you for sticking with this - much appreciated.

Comment: I had a quick play, and I'm seeing similarly odd behaviour when embedding a lib within a lib. However, with 4.6.2 and 1.5 it seems to work ok consistently, so if you can upgrade to that it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Cleared all the caches, and it's actually working now, but the VS UI and ReSharper seem to be 'confused' - maybe a tooling issue I suppose.  Will try the update to 4.6.2.

Comment: Looks like other people are having the same problem - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10037

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141656/discussion-between-neilski-and-iain-brown).